# Merge multiple cases in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

With a `case _ of` syntax like this:

```hs
fun a b c =
    case (a, b, c) of
        (Just True, Just _, _) -> foo
        (Just True, _, Just _) -> foo
        _                      -> bar
```

Can I merge the first two conditions and avoid repeating `foo`?

Alternatively, is there any other (cleaner) way to express that I want to run `foo` if and only if `a` is `Just True` and either `b` or `c` are not `Nothing`?

Comment: Could you set a `d = b or c` right before the case, and then do a `case (a, d)` of `(Just True, not Nothing) -> foo`?

Comment: @rturrado `Maybe` values don't work like that with `or` or `not`.

Comment: @chepner OK, thanks; it was pseudo code. I haven't programmed in Haskell for a while.

Comment: @rturrado You are morally right: Daniel Wagner's answer below essentially follows your approach.

Comment: @chi Haha, thanks! I somehow helped then ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if this looks *cleaner* but you could use the good old pal `if` too:

```hs
fun a b c =
   if a == Just True && (isJust b || isJust c) 
      then foo
      else bar
```

or use guards

```hs
fun a b c =
   case a of
       Just True | isJust b || isJust c -> foo
       _ -> bar
```

without case:

```hs
fun (Just True) b c | isJust b || isJust c = foo
fun _ _ _ = bar
```

all is using [`isJust`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:isJust) and as Daniel pointed out those too will give the piper it's due (pattern match).

Comment: Using `if` here makes a lot of sense as we don't use any unwrapped values in `b` and `c` — we just check if they exist.

Answer (score 11):

You can do something like this:

```
fun a b c = case (a, b <|> c) of
    (Just True, Just _) -> foo
    _ -> bar
```

Of course, that's just hiding the extra match in `(<|>)`, but you gotta pay the piper some time.

If `b` and `c` do not have the same type, you can cause them to with the ill-named [`void`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:void).

Answer (score 6):

Let me complement the other answers with a "boring" alternative:

```
fun a b c = let
   foo' = foo
   in case (a, b, c) of
      (Just True, Just _, _) -> foo'
      (Just True, _, Just _) -> foo'
      _                      -> bar
```

This might or might not answer the intended question, depending on the actual goal.

If the goal was to avoid writing two patterns in the `case`, this of course fails to meet the goal.

If instead the goal was to avoid repeating `foo`, which could be a very long expression (e.g., a long `do` block in some monad), this meets the goal by giving a short name to the long expression.